# Threading with WxPython event in MacOs

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I'm working in WxPython on MacOs X and using pyCharm. What I want to do is when I click on a button on the interface, it generates a new thread, and then this new thread executes my code.

I get this, but it crashes, and I don't know why...

The error that I get is the following:

```
2016-02-22 14:13:36.641 Python[5694:698370] NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds
2016-02-22 14:13:36.643 Python[5694:698370] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91234ae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff977d973c objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9123498d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9035bb32 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 156
4   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff919be488 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 299
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff98a6a053 -[NSTextView _markForTextCheckingAfterChange] + 432
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff911444ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91136165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91135954 __CFRunLoopRun + 948
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91135338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9fc27935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9fc2776f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9fc275af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff988230ee _DPSNextEvent + 1067
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff98bef943 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff98818fc8 -[NSApplication run] + 682
16  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.2.0.dylib    0x0000000103d25418 _ZN14wxGUIEventLoop8OSXDoRunEv + 248
17  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.2.0.dylib    0x0000000103bf260f _ZN13wxCFEventLoop5DoRunEv + 31
18  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.2.0.dylib    0x0000000103b2b0e1 _ZN15wxEventLoopBase3RunEv + 65
19  libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.2.0.dylib    0x0000000103af0787 _ZN16wxAppConsoleBase8MainLoopEv + 103
20  _core_.so                           0x00000001038033dc _ZN7wxPyApp8MainLoopEv + 76
21  _core_.so                           0x000000010384dd8f _wrap_PyApp_MainLoop + 79
22  Python                              0x00000001000c2d32 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20898
23  Python                              0x00000001000c4f93 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
24  Python                              0x000000010003e990 function_call + 176
25  Python                              0x000000010000cde2 PyObject_Call + 98
26  Python                              0x000000010001f43d instancemethod_call + 365
27  Python                              0x000000010000cde2 PyObject_Call + 98
28  Python                              0x00000001000c0c10 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12416
29  Python                              0x00000001000c3bcf PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24639
30  Python                              0x00000001000c4f93 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
31  Python                              0x00000001000c50b6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
32  Python                              0x00000001000e993e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
33  Python                              0x00000001000e9bda PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
34  Python                              0x0000000100100bfd Py_Main + 3101
35  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
```

But sometimes when this happens, I wait, and the code is being executed at the same time...

When I do this again (click the button) it crashes... I think that this is because I don't close the threads, but I don't know if this is needed...

This is the code that I use for creating threads:

```
class CountingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._parent = parent

    def run(self):
        """
        Overrided method.
        """
        self._parent.experiment_button()
```

This class it's called by this event function:

```
def OnButton(self, evt):
    worker = CountingThread(self)
    worker.start()
```

I don't know why this occurs...

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: The first issue I can see is that the calling back from the thread into ``wxPython`` is not thread-safe. You should never call into methods of your GUI directly from a thread, because ``wxPython`` is not designed that way. However, to call back into ``wx`` thread-safely, just wrap the method in a call to ``wx.CallAfter``  as follows: ``wx.CallAfter(self._parent.experiment_button)``

Comment: @nepix32 I've modified that, and know I don't get that error, but it doesn't work as I need, when I press the button, the code is being executed, but the button is still pressed (it seems that the new thread doesn't exists)...


What I want to do, is continue using the interface while the computer is working on the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a classical example of [LongRunningTask](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks). See the last example, which is the easiest to implement, but see also the other possibilities.

Sorry, I was not specific enough in your case: You have to move the long-running part into your thread. When the experiment_button event fires, spin off the thread and report the result back during/after the thread finishes.

```
def run(self):
    """
    Overrided method.
    """
    # put long running part here
    # ... long running task
    # sprinkle with CallAfter as seen fit
    # ... continue task

    # signal the end result back thread-safely
    wx.CallAfter(self._parent.update_result, result)
```

Comment: I know what you say, but I think that I have to change my structure of the code...
I have a method call experiment_button, that executes between some algorithms. This method doesn't finish until have the results, so... I think that the interface get freeze until that moment... I don't know if there are a solution for this problem or not. In case of not, I think that I have to change my structure....
Thank you very much @nepix32